# Create bootable usb for UEFI on mac os Sierra

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media, macos-sierra

I have a mac book pro (mid 2010) and os Sierra and I want to create a Windows bootable USB stick. The other PC has UEFI.

I have tried many things and do not work:

1. I have tried using the bootcamp, as said online, but I think it only works for newer versions than Sierra.
2. I tried from terminal using the following commands

   a)`diskutil eraseDisk ExFat "WINDOWS10" MBR disk2
     cp -rp /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/WINDOWS10/`

   b)`sudo dd if=/path/to/target.img of=/dev/<theusbstick> bs=1m`
3. Then I tried a thing that you copy paste into a folder and there where some problems with some dots in the files (ok, I don't remember much about that)
4. I tried with balenaEtcher, but once it saw that it was a windows.iso, I got the error that it cannot create a bootable windows media
5. I tried with Unetbootin

In all cases, once I put the USB to the PC I want to install windows I get the error that it is not a bootable media.

Do you have any suggestions?

(I also think, but I'm not sure that in (2a) it shouldn't be MBR. Maybe GPT? I tried that instead of MBR, but it didn't recognise the format).

Comment: Facing the **exact** problems. Did you find a way?

Comment: No... I asked from a friend to create a bootable usb for me (in a different device of course)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the windows 10-Iso is an embedded file that is too large for FAT32. You need FAT32 though (i have heard, other methods with NTFS are possible but i can't confirm that, since it didn't work for me)

However, the Microsoft Media Creation Tool doesn't create this large file when it creates a bootable usb. Unfortunately, you can't use the Media Creation Tool on Mac.

I found this solution:

1. Create bootable usb on Windows by using Microsoft Media Creation Tool
2. Make Image of usb on Mac by using Disk Utility App or just copy the files
3. With those files, you can copy them on a MBR Fat32 USB

Edit: I assume that if you only have a mac and the Win-10-Iso available, you can only burn the Iso to a Double Layer-DVD (8.5GB) or Blu-Ray or search for the "NTFS-Partition-Splitting-Solution" where you have both a FAT32 and NFTS-Partition parallel on the USB.